# gcc instantiates template with long instead of __int128

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, gdb

I am dazed and confused. What is happening here in the second call to my `big` template?

```
template <class T> void big(T t) {  }

int main()
{
    big(9223372036854775808);                        // calls big<__int128>
    big(941832094813209483120);                      // calls big<long>
    big(239120938091238093219203810293801923832019); // calls big<__int128>
}
```

Why is a **long template** instantiated for `941832094813209483120`, while the two other values get a **__int128 template**.

This value obviously does **not** fit inside the `long` and seems to result in an overflow (see full gdb session below):

```
big<long> (t=1048147054022350704) at blob.cpp:1
```

I observe this with `gcc-5.2.0` as well as `gcc-4.9.2`, while I use `gdb-7.7.1` for debugging.

This is my full `gdb` session:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at blob.cpp:5
(gdb) s 
big<__int128> (t=0x00000000000000008000000000000000) at blob.cpp:1
(gdb)  
main () at blob.cpp:6
(gdb)  
big<long> (t=1048147054022350704) at blob.cpp:1
(gdb)  
main () at blob.cpp:7
(gdb)  
big<__int128> (t=0x0000000000000000d90567828f8ae8d3) at blob.cpp:1
(gdb)
```

Comment: Assuming long long is not 128bit on your platform then [gcc docs say](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) that *There is no support in GCC for expressing an integer constant of type __int128 for targets with long long integer less than 128 bits wide.* so I would say it is technically not a bug since it is not supported.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Indeed `long` as well as `long long` are both `64bit` wide on my platform. So I understand that I can **not** rely on any of my integer constants above to work! Thank you very much for clarifying.

Comment: I agree it is odd behavior but since it is unsupported, it seems equivalent to saying it is undefined behavior and therefore you can expect nasal demons and such not.

Comment: I believe you should report that as a bug to gcc's bugzilla. For the first constant, gcc says "integer constant is so large that it is unsigned" and then instantiates with __int128? That's not consistent.

Comment: @MarcGlisse well the standard leaves this to the implementation and the gcc documents say it is unsupported. Which seems functionally equivalent to undefined behavior. So isn't inconsistent behavior expected then?

Comment: Just because you are not legally forced to do something clever does not mean you should do something absurd (use __int128 but tell the user that you are using an unsigned type). QoI is important and deserves bug reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the OP has confirmed that long long is 64bit on their system we can see that the [gcc docs on 128-bit Integers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) says:

> There is no support in GCC for expressing an integer constant of type __int128 for targets with long long integer less than 128 bits wide.

So while I agree the behavior is odd, it is technically not a bug since gcc does not support this scenario and explicitly documents this.

Compilers may support extended signed integers, from the draft C++11 standard section 3.9.1:

> There may also be implementation-defined extended signed integer types

but they are implementation-defined and wording for integer literals in section 2.14.2 says:

> If an integer literal cannot be represented by any type in its list and an extended integer type (3.9.1) can
>   represent its value, it **may** have that extended integer type [...]

with emphasis on *may*.